# Find the length of an edge in triangle

Tags: geometry

So my girlfriend is helping a highschool student with geometry, and we have come across what seems like an unsolvable question. I hope I translate the question to English right:

- $AD, BE$ and $CF$ are medians in triangle $ABC$ and they intersect in $G$.
- $AD$ perpendicular $BE$.
- $|AC|=10$ cm.
- $\angle AFC=86°$.
- $|CG|=|AB|$.

Find the length of $AF$.

[image: Image of the triangle]

It feels like we tried everything and we just can't get it.

Comment: apply law of cosine in triangle  AFC  and  AF=FG

Comment: $CG=AB$ doesn't need to be mentioned. It's something that follows from the information given earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the centroid of the triangle (intersection of the medians) cuts the medians in 2:1 proportions. That is, $CG=2FG$. Using that $CG=AB$, you have that $CF=\frac{3GC}{2}=\frac{3AB}{2}=3AF$.

Now you just have to use the cosine law in the triangle $AFC$:

$100=AC^2=AF^2+CF^2-2AF\cdot CF\cos(86º)=10AF^2-6AF^2\cos(86º)$.

Now just solve for $AF$ in the second degree equation.